# How to prevent ssh from adding my key to ssh-agent on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, ssh

I recently started using Snow Leopard (after using Leopard for a few years), and I noticed that when I ssh using a passphrase-protected private key, ssh will automatically add the key to ssh-agent. Question 1: How do I prevent **ssh** from behaving this way (doing the auto-add)?

I am **not** looking to disable the auto-launching of ssh-agent. I actually use it, but I want keys to be added manually (via ssh-add), not automatically.

My current workaround:
I've edited /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist to run with the argument "-t 1" and that works well. But I'm afraid that some software update will revert it.
Question 2: If I put the modified plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ will the one in /System be ignored for my user? This would qualify as a stable workaround.

Comment: Good question, but I don't see the need for the first warning sentence...

Comment: Starting after `ssh-add -D`, what sequence of commands causes the keys to be added? `ssh somwhere` by itself should not add keys. A newly started agent does add keys that have passphrases stored in a keychain and *launchd* will start an agent automatically whenever an SSH command tries to use the advertised agent socket. However, such automatically added keys are immune to the default lifetime `-t` (due to a bug?), so if adding `-t` is effective, then your keys are being added in some other way (`ssh-add` in a shell startup script or some commonly run script?).

Comment: @chris-johnsen are you actually testing this on **Snow Leopard** ? SSH on SL acts differently from Leopard. I know that SL's ssh is adding my key to the ssh-agent because I tried this on a new Mac. I can clear the stored key with "ssh-add -D" afterward and then I get the passphrase dialog box again, but that's not an acceptable solution. Logging out will also clear the stored key (this behavior is consistent with quitting ssh-agent). The problem is reproducible. I'm not the only one: http://www.serverfault.cms-forex.info/details/144147/ssh-passphrase-remembered-in-macosx-snow-leopard/

Comment: Yes, I am using Snow Leopard, but I have always used a “stock” *ssh* instead of the version that Apple provides. I reproduced your “ssh auto-adds” behavior with Apple’s *ssh*. When I investigated the code, I found an undocumented setting that looks like it will solve your problem (though you will have to give up the GUI-based passphrase prompting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Automatically Added Keys

There are three ways SSH keys are added to *ssh-agent* in Snow
Leopard.

- manually, with *ssh-add*,
- automatically, by *ssh* when you supply a key’s passphrase via
  the GUI prompt, and
- automatically, by *ssh-agent* when it first starts.

The last two methods are Apple extensions: there are no “automatic”
additions with stock OpenSSH. All references to *ssh*, *ssh-agent*,
and *ssh-add* below are to Apple’s Snow Leopard versions unless
I prefix the program name with the adjective “stock”.

You can disable all of Apple’s keychain-oriented SSH modifications
with a (undocumented?) preference setting:

```
defaults write org.openbsd.openssh KeychainIntegration -bool false
```

### Keys Added Automatically By *ssh*

(This is the part I missed in the previous version of my original
answer since I usually use a “stock” *ssh*.)

Whenever *ssh* tries to use a passphrase protected SSH key to
authenticate itself to a remote host, it will issue a GUI prompt for
the SSH key’s password. The key is also loaded into the agent (if
the passphrase is correct) whether or not you mark the “Remember
password in my keychain” checkbox.

There are two (undocumented?) ways to prevent *ssh* from issuing
this GUI prompt (and thus adding the SSH key to the *ssh-agent*):

- A preference setting:

  ```
    defaults write org.openbsd.openssh AskPassGUI -bool false
  ```
- An
  [`ssh_config`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ssh_config.5.html)
  entry (or `-o` option to *ssh*) that specifies `AskPassGUI no`.

  (see `keychain_read_passphrase` in
  [`keychain.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/keychain.c);
  the `oAskPassGUI` parameter comes from the `AskPassGUI`
  configuration setting)

When `AskPassGUI` is disabled, *ssh* will prompt you in the normal
way for the key’s password (i.e. through the tty).

You could also avoid automatic adds from *ssh* by using a “stock”
*ssh* (e.g. OpenSSH compiled by
[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/),
[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) “duplicates” from
[homebrew-alt](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt), or
[Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/)).

### Keys Added Automatically By *ssh-agent*

The keys that *ssh-agent* automatically adds are those that have
their passphrases stored in a keychain.
These **“remembered keys”** are automatically added when a new
*ssh-agent* starts.
There is no command line or configuration option (other than
`KeychainIntegration`, described above) to prevent *ssh-agent* from
automatically loading the “remembered keys” (see the call to
`process_add_from_keychain` (defined in
[`keychain.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/keychain.c)) from `main` in
[`ssh-agent.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/ssh-agent.c)).
If, however, you can arrange to lock the keychains that store your
SSH key passphrases, you can click Cancel when *ssh-agent* asks to
unlock the keychain(s) and effectively get *ssh-agent* to skip
adding these “remembered keys” when it first starts.

If there is no *ssh-agent* running, your first use of *ssh* will
likely trigger *launchd* to start an *ssh-agent* which will load all
the “remembered keys”. This makes it seem like *ssh* is loading the
keys into the agent, but it is really the agent itself that is
loading the keys. It only does this automatically when it first
starts.

The `-k` option of *ssh-add* provides a manual way to add the
“remembered keys” (see `add_from_keychain` in
[`ssh-add.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/ssh-add.c)
which ends up as a message to the agent which calls
`process_add_from_keychain` from `process_message` in
[`ssh-agent.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/ssh-agent.c)).

## *launchd* Configuration

You are right that a system update could overwrite your modification to the file in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/`. You should always avoid changing things under `/System/`; most things can be (re)configured without making changes there. In this case, it looks like you should be able to override the system default *launchd* job specification on a per-user basis with a file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

From what I can tell<sup>1</sup>, entries are loaded in this order<sup>2</sup>:

1. `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`
2. `/Library/LaunchAgents/`
3. `/Network/Library/LaunchAgents/` (not present on most systems)
4. `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/`

It does not seem to be documented, but only the first job configuration for each Label (e.g. `org.openbsd.ssh-agent`) will be kept. Any configuration from a later directory with the same Label as a configuration from an earlier directory is effectively skipped.

---

<sup>1</sup>
See
`NSStartSearchPathEnumeration`  used in [`launchctl.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-329.3.3/launchd/src/launchctl.c)
and defined in
[`NSSystemDirectories.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/include/NSSystemDirectories.h)/[`NSSystemDirectories.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/gen/NSSystemDirectories.c).

<sup>2</sup>
*launchd* also looks in the `LaunchDaemons/` directories next to the various `LaunchAgents/` directories for other types of jobs.

Comment: @chris-johnsen I realize you're trying to be helpful, but please try to understand the details of the problem before laying out an entire step-by-step solution.

Comment: I will try your "AskPassGUI" solution when I'm at my SL machine. If it works I'll accept your answer. Also, I reverted /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist and put my modified copy in /Library/LaunchAgents/. My mod was loaded.

Comment: The "AskPassGUI" worked. Looks like it's actually the passphrase gui that did the adding to ssh-agent.